# Objective-C: Keeping Variable Alive in Another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

In my app, when the user launched the app, I create an instance of a class in my AppDelegate and call a method in the class which compares all of the user's iOS contacts to find which ones are using my app, and puts those contacts into an NSMutableArray

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
... 
GetContactClass *contact = [[GetContactClass alloc] init];
[contact getAllContacts];  
...
}
```

**GetContactClass.h**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *appContacts;
```

At the end of the getAllContacts method, I NSLog out appContacts and it works fine.

However, later in the app I try to set an NSMutableArray in a ViewController to equal appContacts, but I get a (null) array.

**ViewController.m**

```
self.searchableContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

GetContactClass *contact = [[GetContactClass alloc] init];
self.searchableContacts = contact.appContacts;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an entirely new instance which hasn't been asked to collect all contacts, so it hasn't stored them. By the look of the code the instance which has stored them has been destroyed. As you're running this on the main thread you might as well just ask the new instance to get contacts and delete the code for the old one. It's better however to run the contacts collection on a background thread and keep the result till you need it, in a retained instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use this data in all app you must use a Pattern Design Singleton:
In objective-c:

```
@implementation Settings
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static Settings *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Other way is change retain to strong but this is a bad idea and put this property in appDelegate and call all times APPDelegate get property.